# Is there a way to change the color of the layout in PopOver

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Popover menu with material-ui and I have noticed that in default mode the library puts a layer to capture outside clicks to close the menu. I was wondering is there a way to change the background color or assign a class to this layer to give it some style?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any possibilities in `v0.19.3` ([Popover.js component](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v0.19.3/src/Popover/Popover.js)), but looks like the new version (they are currently working on, still in beta) will [have such possibility](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/Popover/Popover.js#L375):

```
<Popover
  backdropInvisible={false}
  backdropClassName="MyBackDropClass"
  ... 
>
  ...
</Popover>
```

Also it looks like it will be possible to provide your [own backdrop component](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/93baf08fb96ee7d30695e9eaea95219c4e7a6200/src/internal/Modal.js#L55) or provide [transition delay](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/93baf08fb96ee7d30695e9eaea95219c4e7a6200/src/internal/Modal.js#L64).

If the project you're working on can rely on beta version of `material-ui`, just test it out:

```
npm install material-ui@next
```

Comment: mmm not right now, I'm using version 0.19.3 and I'd to look how to upgrade. But it could be a way. Thanks